# Multiple filters for html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I have an html table in my view that I want to filter with multiple filters. In this case, I have 3 filters, but I can have much more.

Here is a little part of the code, to show the problem

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   
   

    $('#datefilterfrom').on("change", filterRows);
    $('#datefilterto').on("change", filterRows);
    $('#projectfilter').on("change", filterProject);
    $('#servicefilter').on("change", filterService);
});

function filterRows() {
    var from = $('#datefilterfrom').val();
    var to = $('#datefilterto').val();

    if (!from && !to) { // no value for from and to
        return;
    }

    from = from || '1970-01-01'; // default from to a old date if it is not set
    to = to || '2999-12-31';

    var dateFrom = moment(from);
    var dateTo = moment(to);

    $('#testTable tr').each(function (i, tr) {
        var val = $(tr).find("td:nth-child(2)").text();
        var dateVal = moment(val, "DD/MM/YYYY");
        var visible = (dateVal.isBetween(dateFrom, dateTo, null, [])) ? "" : "none"; // [] for inclusive
        $(tr).css('display', visible);
    });
}
function filterProject() {
    let dumb = this.options.selectedIndex;
    dumb = this.options[dumb].innerHTML;
    var filter, table, tr, td, i;
    filter = dumb.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("testTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
        if (td) {
            if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                tr[i].style.display = "table-row";
            } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }

    }
}

function filterService() {
    let dumb = this.options.selectedIndex;
    dumb = this.options[dumb].innerHTML;
    var filter, table, tr, td, i;
    filter = dumb.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("testTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3];
        if (td) {
            if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                tr[i].style.display = "table-row";
            } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }

    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/moment/moment/2.2.1/min/moment.min.js"></script>
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h4>Date from</h4>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="datefilterfrom" data-date-split-input="true">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h4>Date to</h4>
            <input type="date"  class="form-control" id="datefilterto" data-date-split-input="true">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <h4>Project</h4>
           <select id="projectfilter" name="projectfilter" class="form-control"><option value="1">Test project</option><option value="2">Test2</option></select>
        </div>
     <div class="col-md-2">
            <h4>Service</h4>
           <select id="servicefilter" name="servicefilter" class="form-control"><option value="1">Test service</option><option value="2">Test2 service</option></select>
        </div>
    </div>
<table id="testTable" class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">Date</th>
                    <th scope="col">Project</th>
                   <th scope="col">Service</th>
               
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="report">
              <tr>
                <td class="proposalId">9</td><td> 17/07/2018</td> <td> Test project</td><td> Test service</td>
              </tr>
              <tr><td class="proposalId">8</td><td> 18/07/2018</td><td> Test project</td><td> Test2  service</td></tr>
              <tr><td class="proposalId">7</td><td> 17/07/2018</td><td> Test2</td><td> Test2 service</td></tr>
              <tr style=""><td class="proposalId">3</td><td> 19/07/2018</td><td> Test2</td><td> Test service</td></tr>
              
    </tbody>
        </table>
```

If you set filters like this 
[image]

You will have this

[image]

This is not right. Because I need to have only test 2 project, so one row.

Where is my problem and How I can solve it?

Here is codepen for code

> https://codepen.io/suhomlineugene/pen/pZqyEN

Comment: You have to have an active filter functions to return a result to an other active filter function... Than at the end, update the table. That is a conception issue which I think is "too broad" for SO. Alternatively, I would suggest you to look at [Datatables column filtering](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/columnFiltering.html). ;)

Comment: you mean, use Datatables? @LouysPatriceBessette

Comment: Exactly... The feature you want already is coded and battlefield tested. You just will have the styling to improve to your taste.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you have a separate function for each of your filters, each of which ignores the settings from the other filters and overwrites their results.

Instead you'll need to combine those into a single function which takes *all* the filters into account.

Rather than literally combining all the code into one complex function, which would be difficult to maintain, one approach would be to have a single master function that makes all the rows visible, then calls each of the other filter functions in turn; those functions would only hide the rows they're filtering out.  What's left visible at the end would be the rows that match all the filter selections.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#datefilterfrom, #datefilterto, #projectfilter, #servicefilter').on("change", filterAll);
});

function filterAll() {
    $('#testTable tr').show();
    filterRows();
    filterProject();
    filterService();
    // ...etc
}

function filterRows() {  // repeat for filterProject(), filterService(), etc
    // same as your original code, except only hide non-matching rows, do not
    // show matching rows (because filterAll() already took care of that, and
    // you don't want to undo what other filters may have hidden.)
}
```

(Alternatively, instead of showing everything and then having each individual filter hide rows incrementally, you could have filterAll() build an array of all the rows, pass it to the individual filter functions which will remove items from it, then use the end result to show/hide the appropriate rows in one go.)

Answer (score 0):

Not going to rewrite this all for you but will give you a basic outline for the text only searches:

Create array of the filter data from the top inputs. By adding a `data-col` to each of those filter controls you can easily determine which column in table to match to

So the filters array would look something like:

```
[
  {col:3, value:'test project'}
]
```

Then use jQuery `filter()` on the rows and use `Array#every()` on the filterValues array and look for the matching cell text using the column index from each filter object

```
var $rows = $('tbody#report tr')
// add a class `table-filter` to all the top filtering elements
var $filters = $('.table-filter').change(function() {

  // create array of filter objects
  var filterArr = $filters.filter(function() {
    return this.value
  }).map(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    var value = $el.is('select') ? $el.find(':selected').text() : $el.val()
    return {
      col: $el.data('col'),
      value: value.toLowerCase()
    }
  }).get();

  if (!filterArr.length) {
    // no filters show all rows
    $rows.show()
  } else {
    // hide all then filter out the  matching rows
    $rows.hide().filter(function() {
      var $row = $(this);
      // match every filter to whole row
      return filterArr.every(function(filterObj, i) {
        var cellText = $row.find('td').eq(filterObj.col).text().trim().toLowerCase();
        return cellText.includes(filterObj.value);
      })
    })
    // show the matches
    .show()
  }
});
```

[Working demo for the two text search fields](https://codepen.io/charlietfl/pen/qyLaBN?editors=0010)

Comment: Should be failry easy to add in the date matching also into the jQuery filter() part

Comment: I tried like this `  var value = $el.is('select') ? $el.find(':selected').text() : moment($el.val(), "YYYY-MM-DD").format('DD/MM/YYYY')`

But it seems not working

Comment: How I can do this? Not very experienced in jquery